# How do I produce this pentagon in the link in the simplest way, with added vertex names?

Tags: latex, mathematics

How can we produce this picture https://snipboard.io/oVp3Ic.jpg, with added vertex names (e.g. A,B,C etc.) in the simplest way possible? Eventually I'll need to put this picture into a LaTeX file that'll be transformed into PDF.

Thank you!

Comment: You could use almost any vector image editor, such as Adobe Illustrator, CorelDraw, or Inkscape (which is free).

Comment: You *could* also use practically any raster editor - Gimp, Photoshop, PaintShop Pro - But vector, as Billy suggests, would probably be better due to the resolution independence.

Comment: I would draw it with a pen, ruler and compass on paper. But what's the actual problem? Should the image be written as text in some graphics definition language that you do not read & speak well enough? Or is getting angles and lengths (especially pieces x and 7cm) right too difficult? Or what? Do you search a general elementary geometry image production toolset and showed to us only a random example which is not at all your actual problem? You'll get voted out if you do not include some details which show the actual problem.

Comment: Why dont you use tikz? Then you can edit it iside your TeX markup.

Answer (score 2):

If you know basics of Illustrator, you can try like this:

1. For the shapes - Draw your shape and place circles/squares to represent angles and select all and use Pathfinder tool to outline them and then you can select and remove unnecessary segments using Direct Selection Tool.

[image]

2. For text part

[image]